# How do you normally show this "Passwords" button on the iOS keyboard?

Tags: ios

Bit of a strange question: we are working on an iOS app made with a 3rd-party engine (Unity). We've encountered what appears to be a bug in the engine - randomly, when the soft keyboard is shown, a "Passwords" button appears at the top of the keyboard. Tapping this button brings up a list of websites that you've previously saved passwords for.

[image: Keyboard with passwords button]

I've never seen this button in any other circumstance and have no idea what causes it to appear. What I'm looking for right now is information about this button - any API docs about it, what Objective-C / Swift code you'd normally use to show it, etc. I'm hoping this additional information will make it easier to find a workaround or at least file a bug report with Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS apps you get automatically this password autofill button on the top of the keyboard if you set the `textContentType` property of UITextField to any of these:

• username,

• password,

• newPassword,

• oneTimeCode

You can read more about this on this link: [Enabling Password AutoFill on a Text Input View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view)